# How to get prepared SQL statement from JdbcDaoSupport (Spring)

Tags: database, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I use JdbcDaoSupport (Spring) approch to access data from my DB.

I would like to get prepared SQL statement for logging. Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ramblingabout.wordpress.com/2007/01/03/logging-sql-queries-with-spring/